# Find inverse of a quadratic polynomial by 'completing the square'

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse, quadratics, completing-the-square

I have been asked to find the inverse of an equation that has the form
$y=ax^2 + by -c$

EDIT: Which is $y=4x^2+ 8x -3$ in the graph below

Using a graphing calculator, and trial and error, I can find the equation in the form of

$y=af(k(x-d)^2)+ c$

EDIT: Which is $y=4(x+1)^2-7$ in the graph below.

NOTE: This equation has been graphed, and falls directly below the $y=4x^2+8x-3$ (because they are the equal)

From this notation, I can then easily find the inverse.

[image]

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to do this algebraically. I am told I should 'complete the square'. I have used multiple inverse calculators on many websites and the all have given me different steps/answers.

How can I convert this equation into the form $y=af(k(x-d))+c$ algebraically?

(Seen above as $y=4(x+1)^2-7$ )

EDIT:

To convert from  $4x^2+ 8x -3$ to $4(x+1)^2-7$, I believe I am just finding the vertex and then applying the transformations from 0,0.

Comment: $a x + b y - c$ defines a function of 2 variables, which you can't graph in the 2D plane. $a x + b y - c = 0$ defines a line in the plane. Neither interpretation has any `square to complete` so it's hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the question.

Comment: The title and first line still refer to $a x + b y - c$. Also, an equation is not a function, and does not have an inverse function. If this is homework, please copy the question literally, and show your attempts at solving it. You may find [Completing the Square](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/completing-square.html) useful.

Comment: Wouldn't the inverse of an expression  poo (x,y) simply be poo (y,x)?  Wouldn't this inverse be ay+bx-c.  If not what is the definition of inverse?

Comment: Dvix ax+by -c isn't even an equation.

Comment: Sorry again. It is fixed now?

Comment: I figured the graph demonstrated the concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion you received is good, you shall proceed as to "absorb" the factor $x$:
$$
y = 4x^{\,2}  + 8x - 3 = 4x^{\,2}  + 8x + 4 - 4 - 3 = 4\left( {x + 1} \right)^{\,2}  - 7
$$
and then, clearly
$$
\left( {x + 1} \right)^{\,2}  = \frac{{y + 7}}
{4}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad x =  \pm \frac{1}
{2}\sqrt {y + 7}  - 1
$$
Of course, this is not always viable in general.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work when b=2

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the function $y=ax^2+bx-c$, then the inverse function will be:
$$x=ay^2+by-c\\ay^2+by-c-x=0\\y_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2+4a(c+x)}}{2a}$$
So your inverse function is actually 2 functions.

Comment: While this is insightful, part of the question requires completing the square, not using the quadratic formula.

Comment: Then do it by completing the square.  The idea is to solve it when it has been inverted.  Nobody (except your teacher) cares how you solve it.  So solve it by completing the square.

Comment: Basically, the whole formula, is completing the square.